# JavaScript: Is it impossible to extend a single `ternary` operation to more than one layer?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

In the following example, I've used a ternary operation instead of repeating `else if` s. And the code fails to run. I wonder what exactly is wrong with this snippet of code.

---

```
var ran = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

(ran <= 25) ?
     ran = 1;
    : (ran <= 50) ?
         ran = 2;
        : (ran <= 75) ?
             ran = 3;
            : ran = 4;

alert(ran);
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(ran / 25)`?

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with it is that you stuck it full of extra semicolons. Take 'em out. It's all one statement. One semicolon at the end, that's all you need and all the compiler can make any sense of.

Thank you for indenting it clearly. I hate it when people use the ternary operator without proper indenting.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Where exactly should I add additional parentheses?

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre You know what, the way you've indented it, it's clear enough as it is. Never mind the parens. And without the semicolons, it actually works. Bravo!

Comment: Thanks. I needed to convert the range 1-25 to a single number "1" so that I can use the "ran" variable in the expression bit of a switch statement.